# regular expression for same structure but different words in number(counting)

Tags: php, python, regex

I have a text file of links after scrapping, I need to make a regular expression for these links so i can extract them from a file, but different links have same structure but different in length, like

```
https://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/12/billionaire-richard-branson-learned-a-key-business-lesson-playing-tennis.html
```

and this:

```
https://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/12/hedge-fund-bonus-makeover.html
```

I can successfully make RE for the base domain, but after that title give me a tough time, mine is

```
[h][t][t][p][s]:\/\/[w][w][w].[c][n][b][c].[c][o][m]\/[2][0][1][5-8]
```

for `https://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/11/`
but dont know how to make for further with diiferent words for different links ahead,

Comment: I have tried something of my own [here](https://regex101.com/r/8iIuYL/2). Nevertheless, you can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: You should really read up on the basics of regular expression syntax. Most of those square brackets are totally unnecessary, but then you've left unescaped `.`s that match any character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex to something like this:

```
preg_match("/http.*:\/\/www\.cnbc\.com\/201[5-8].*/", $string, $match);
```

This matches the address with `http` or `https`.
Then any link that is between 2015 and 2018.

See here how it works:
https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/o7p

Comment: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1596553, 1596664), match='https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/02/heres-the-most-al> after printing , how to increase the match length , because it is not print full link

Comment: What is that? I don't understand what that is.

Comment: the links after matching them from a file it print like this in python

Comment: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1596553, 1596664), match='https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/02/heres-the-most-al>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1596665, 1596747), match='https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/02/how-gary-cohn-got>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1596748, 1596840), match='https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/02/how-richard-brans>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1596841, 1596917), match='https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/02/how-the-nra-might>

Comment: but match length is not enough to hold all the url, if you know about it it will be convinient for me

Comment: It doesn't help if you paste 50 of those strings here. I do not understand what it is! Your question stated two simple links now you add "stuff" and talk about lenght. I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things,

```
https?://\S+?cnbc\.com\S+
```

will probably do, see https://regex101.com/r/ci3O1I/1/ for a demo.

Comment: https://www.cnbc.com/ali-montag/?page=31 this one is also selected in links file which is not required